# Is it possible to pass null type in place of generic type parameter?

Tags: kotlin, generics

I am going to use [the following method](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-mongodb/blob/3.3.2/spring-data-mongodb/src/main/kotlin/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/MongoOperationsExtensions.kt#L182-L184) from Spring Data Kotlin extensions:

```kotlin
inline fun <reified T : Any> MongoOperations.bulkOps(bulkMode: BulkMode, collectionName: String? = null): BulkOperations
```

The question is: can I somehow avoid specifying `T` assuming I do not want to provide entity class name (that's because I will explicitly specify `collectionName`, and in this case class [type can be `null`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-mongodb/blob/3.3.2/spring-data-mongodb/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/MongoOperations.java#L394-L402)). I would like to type something like:

```kotlin
val ops = mongoTemplate.bulkOps<null>(BulkOperations.BulkMode.UNORDERED, collectionName = "i_know_better")
```

Is there a type literal for `null` with which I can parameterize `bulkOps`?

Answer (score 3):

To answer the question in general, you can use `Nothing?` to represent the type that only contains the value `null`.

That being said, as @Fred already said, the method you're considering here explicitly states `T : Any`, meaning only non-nullable types are allowed. And it makes sense given that the function is accessing the class of `T`.

Comment: The underlying [bulkOps](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-mongodb/blob/3.3.2/spring-data-mongodb/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/MongoOperations.java#L398) from Java API can accept null type, so I could imagine allowing `Nothing?`, but I got the idea: it's not possible with the current design of given Kotlin extension. Thanks!

Comment: @Kirill what do you mean by "Java can accept null type"? Java doesn't have nullable types, and null is a value not a type. You cannot pass a "null" class in Java there, you could only call an API that doesn't take a class as argument

Comment: or you could just use Unit

Answer (score 2):

I think the short answer is no.

You seem to confuse types with values. `null` is a value and not a type so it cannot be used as a type in generic methods.

In your specific example, even if you could use null, looking at the code what would you expect to happen?

```
@Suppress("EXTENSION_SHADOWED_BY_MEMBER")
inline fun <reified T : Any> MongoOperations.bulkOps(bulkMode: BulkMode, collectionName: String? = null): BulkOperations =
        if (collectionName != null) bulkOps(bulkMode, T::class.java, collectionName)
        else bulkOps(bulkMode, T::class.java)
```

As you can see there's always `T::class.java` being called. What would be the result of `null::class.java`?

I'm unfamiliar with the Spring Data so I can't really provide an alternative, but I'd say you either need to search for another method or use an appropriate class here. The generic type is marked as `T : Any` so presumably it can be any non-nullable type. I wonder if `Unit` would work. Again, I'm not sure what this class is used for.

Comment: Just checked: `Unit` does not work, it has own type. Thanks you, I will just stick with [`bulkOps` with no class name from java API](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-mongodb/blob/3.3.2/spring-data-mongodb/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/MongoTemplate.java#L735-L737)